# ¿Cómo invocar las instancias de clases para un mejor rendimiento?

Tags: c#, instancias

Me encuentro realizando un programa en `C#`, en el cual creo `instancias` de `clases/objetos`, el detalle es que las creo junto con su `declaración`, por ejemplo:

```
NombreClase objeto = new NombreClase(MisParametros);
```

Esta línea de código se ejecuta cada 10 segundos, por lo tanto a lo que sé por ahora, es que cada `instancia` generada de cada `objeto` se queda de alguna manera **"almacenada"** en memoria.

Por lo tanto, la cuestión sería:

> ¿Si cada 10 segundos se crea una instancia junto su declaración, afectaría el rendimiento del programa?

¿Se podría resolver de la siguiente forma?

```
NombreClase objeto; //Declaro el objeto estáticamente(por así decirlo)
```

Después llamo el objeto desde donde lo necesito para crear una nueva instancia:

```
objeto = new NombreClase(MisParametros);//llamo el objeto/clase en mi función para instanciarlo
```

> ¿Sería lo mismo, o sí habría diferencia en el rendimiento del programa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al realizar algunos tests, resulta que es preferible declarar el objeto en el scope en el que será utilizado. Y tiene sentido, ya que el Garbage Collector está bastante optimizado y es capaz de reconocer estos objectos y limpiar la memoria. Estas son las clases y métodos que utilicé en el benchmark:

```
      class MiClase
      {
         public bool BoolProp { get; set; }
         public MiClase ClaseProp { get; set; }
         public long LongProp { get; set; }
      }

     
      public void Inline()
      {
         for (long i = 0; i < 1_000_000_000; i++)
         {
            var obj = new MiClase();
         }
      }


      private MiClase _obj;
      
      public void Private()
      {
         for (long i = 0; i < 1_000_000_000; i++)
         {
            _obj = new MiClase();
         }
      }

      private static MiClase staticObj;
      
      public void Static()
      {
         for (long i = 0; i < 1_000_000_000; i++)
         {
            staticObj = new MiClase();
         }
      }
```

Y los resultados fueron los siguientes:

[image: Resultados]

Cabe recalcar, que a las variables del método Private y Static se les está asignando memoria porque su scope es mucho más amplio y dura durante toda la prueba.

Por eso, tendrías que repensar tu diseño y ver el por qué se tienen que crear tantos objectos y determinar un scope adecuado.

Si es inevitable el crear demasiados y el scope es bastante amplio, entonces tu mayor problema sería la memoria y quizá podrías hacer uso de una llamada al Garbage Collector (GC.Collect()), pero ten en cuenta que consume demasiados recursos del CPU así que no se debe de llamar repetidamente ni muy seguido. En general, no es recomendable realizarlo (por lo mismo) pero sí pueden haber casos extremos en los que se llega a utilizar.

Finalmente, te dejo la tool que utilicé [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) para que puedas realizar pruebas con tu código y analizar los resultados.